# nginx proxy pass and auth_basic prompting login on each request

Tags: nginx

I have a simple reverse proxy set up that moves `/` to a localhost daemon for testing purposes.  Basically it's a proxy at the root and the auth is working.  The issue is that it's prompting for the login on each request.  Currently it's something like this:

```
 server {

        listen 80;
        server_name  whatever.com.net;
        access_log /var/log/prototype/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/prototype/error.log;

        auth_basic "Prototype Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;

                #auth_basic "Prototype Login";
                #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        }
}
```

I'm pretty sure I get why this is happening, but I'm not sure if there's a fix as it's currently set up. The localhost app has zero care about this authentication, so there's not downstream header issues, this is strictly nginx prompting for login on each request.  Is there a way to better handle this type of proxy pass to only have an initial auth via nginx?

Comment: Check your error logs, is there anything in there?

Comment: Sorry, I just got back to this and it's the same problem, every single request wants the login.  The logs are good, I can see where it's authenticating with the credentials, it's just that every single request triggers the prompt and that can't work.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?